# php shell_exec() command pop out error and permission denied ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

This is the main index.php file where I run my code to generate a video thumbnail with ffmpeg but it has no lucks at all I have been searching online for a lot of solution but nothing comes out i will be very appreciate if you guys can help me out. The shell_exec() keep giving me error

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$ffmpeg = "/Users/mac/Documents/ffmpeg/3.1.4/bin/ffmpeg";
$videoFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$imageFile = "1.jpg";
$size = "320x240";
$getFromSecond = 5;
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile 2>&1";

    echo shell_exec($cmd);


echo shell_exec('whoami');
if(!shell_exec($cmd)){


    echo "thumbnail created";
}else{
    echo "error creating thumbnail";
}






}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that it says **permission denied**?

Comment: Yes it keep saying permission denied and I dont know whats wrong I have followed the abell.com tutorial which end up error but the video tutorial do works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT4hN5o57hI&index=3&list=PLf1QYWO6pRZiBa_7JlpR-ejHaIHzFblMq

Comment: After I change it to exec() it didnt prompt out any error but no image was created in my folder

Comment: The program appears to be in your personal directory. Does the user the web server runs as have permission to enter it?

Comment: Ya i able to run the localhost xampp server on my own mac what do you mean by does the web server have permission to enter it?

Comment: Well, you know, computers protect files so not everybody can read and edit them. That's accomplished with a combination of users and groups that are granted or defined access to stuff. Home directories are specially protected because they're supposed to contain people's personal stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user which is attempting to run this file does not have the correct permissions (usually `www-data`). To test this theory, try running with `sudo`:

```
shell_exec('sudo -u user -p pass -s $ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile 2>&1');
```

You could also configure Apache to run your virtual host as a different user other than `www-data` or change permissions to the files you would like `www-data` to access:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30879/what-user-should-apache-and-php-be-running-as-what-permissions-should-var-www

Comment: **sudo: unknown user** it gave me this and there is no image created

Comment: @user3711175 You need to change where it says `user` & `pass` to the user `mac` and the password for the `mac` account

Comment: **sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified** and now it gave me this

Comment: @user3711175 Is there another account (admin account) other than `mac` on your machine?

Comment: ya one other is guest user

Comment: Another way to avoid compromising the security of your machine is by moving the `ffmpeg/3.1.4/bin/ffmpeg` into a folder which has permissions for Apache. For testing purposes you could just move the folder into your `htdocs`, `www` what ever it's called on your machine and change your path on your original script. Make sure to use your orginal script as the sudo one I created will cause you an error.

Comment: original script means I use the original $ffmpeg code not the sudo one is it?

Comment: is a success I done it thanks so much for your help kitson

Comment: Ah good stuff. So its probably worth moving that into a folder which is not published to the web but your Apache account still has access.

Comment: do you mind if i ask if i want to host it on the webserver something like aws is it possible?

Comment: Yeah it should be fine on AWS but most web hosting companies deny the use of `shell_exec()` so check before you purchase.

Comment: kitson88 do you mind giving me your email address so i can consult you in the future if I encounter any problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126081/discussion-between-kitson88-and-user3711175).

Answer (score 0):

Your www-data might not have access to run the ffmpeg.

For ubuntu 22.10, Edit permission to run ffmpeg without password by,

`vim /etc/sudoers.d`

Add line,

`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ffmpeg`

And then change your ffmpeg command to look like,

"sudo -u root /full/path/to/ffmpeg -i xyz... ... 2>&1"

2>&1 is to display any error on the execution.